# Adding lombok to Android project that uses Java 8

Tags: android, lombok

I created a brand new Android project and added the lombok support.

Everything worked great while I developed on Java 7 but one I updated the language level to 8 the lombok compiler stopped functioning.

The changes I've made in gradle to update the language to java 8 are:

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

and

```
compileOptions {
targetCompatibility 1.8
sourceCompatibility 1.8
```

}

My gradle is:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.instatrivia"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"

// Android support libs
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

// dagger
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger_version"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger_version"
//    testApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger_version"

// rx java/android
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
// Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
// explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'

provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

// misc
provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14"
compile "com.google.guava:guava:$rootProject.guavaVersion"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

}
```

The error I'm getting during build is:

```
    Warning:You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled.
Your processor is: com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BatchProcessingEnvImpl
Lombok supports: sun/apple javac 1.6, ECJ
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `jack` and `lombok` together, so you need to choose what you need more.

Unless you really need it, it may be acceptable to disable `jack` (which is now [announced dead](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html), anyway) as certain Java 8 features can be substituted with external libraries (i.e. Lambdas with [retro-lambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)).